# Starting activity inside the tabhost

Tags: android

I have a tabbased application. On one of my tabs I have a listview with productcells. When the user taps the row a new activity is launched. Is it possible to start the new activity as normal but without "losing" the tabbar at the bottom. Because now my tabbar is gone when I start the new activity. Much like the navigation hierachy on iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

It basically explains how to use `ActivityGroup` to achieve that effect. I usually don't recommend this approach, not only because sometimes gets a PITA to handle but because it too iPhone-like. Remember, you are developing for Android.

**Edit:** with regards to Mur's comment... it's not a matter of fanaticism (I even own an iPhone). So what's wrong with doing Android apps in the iPhone way? Basically, the Android OS is not designed to be used in that way. For instance, the nested tabs: using `ActivityGroup` forces you to handle the back button manually, the activities themselves don't work as they should (what you do with `ActivityGroup` is getting the Activities' Views and play with them), you have to create public static non-final objects to handle simple things like showing a dialog, etc.

Just saying.

Comment: i don't understand, what's wrong in using good 'iPhone-like' features? Why do we use touchscreen at all, it's toooooo iPhone-like

Comment: No man, the touchscreens were invented years before the first iPhone was created. Wikipedia is your friend.

Comment: You are right, but they would so famous in mobile devices first after iPod came to the market. Or am i wrong? I mean, it was an example, that it's not so bad to use nice things, which would be used in concurent platform. Don't you think so?

Comment: I agree with you... that's what I edited my answer to expand my opinion.

Comment: The link here is dead, by the way.