# Android: How can I open up new activitys in the tab content, instead of full screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabbar

My Android app is created with a tab bar and the root activity is extending TabActivity. The problem I have is that I always want the tab bar to be visible.

Lets say that one of the activitys in one of the tabs have a button and when I tap that button I want to open up a new activity with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The new activity opens up in full screen over the tab bar. I want it to show up in the FrameLayout where I have the tab content so that the tab bar is still visible. I want to use an activity so that I can use back stack etc. This must be standard in an app using a tab bar, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting activity inside the tabhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324938/starting-activity-inside-the-tabhost)

Comment: As I can't add a comment in that post I'm doing it here. From what I understand from that post there is a way but it is a "hack" and that Android isn't built to use this idea of an UI. So if my app is divided into five different large parts, that is perfect to divide into tabs (like I do on the iPhone). How would you solve the same thing without a tab bar? Or should I use a tab bar but open up new activitys full screen?

Comment: you shouldn't use the regular old tabs android provides you with.  create your own custom tabs and include them in every layout.

Comment: @binnyb Why not use the regular old tabs provided by Android? (Asking because I'm a newbie to Android :D)

Comment: they do not seem to be made for customized use. they are very good for  basic activities living inside each tab.  each tab holding an activity can become quite sluggish and you run into the problem the question is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a tabbed layout you should use a `TabHost` and a `TabWidget` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but i think that if you want the activity to display within the tab content you should declare a tabspec, like for regular tabs, or directly set the TabHost current tab to the tab/activity you want to display?

Comment: But will this make it possible for me to use back stack for example?

Comment: this is where it get's bumpy :/ as all activities are loaded within the frame_layout of the tabcontent, and only paused/resumed, handling the activity stack is impossible for me ... instead i found a way for my app to start Activities for result, using the Dialog theme, and this is really convenient for my case, i think it's not a good and long term solution :/

Answer (score -1):

Seems like it is like Cristian says, [there is no good way of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324938/starting-activity-inside-the-tabhost)

From what I understand from that post there is a way but it is a "hack" and that Android isn't built to use this idea of an UI.

I have some questions about this, though:

So if my app is divided into five different large parts, that is perfect to divide into tabs (like I do on the iPhone). How would you solve this UI in Android in a good way without a tab bar? Or should I use a tab bar but open up new activitys full screen?